# Constant beeping when playing 1st order ambisonic audio in Unity app deployed on Samsung S7

Tags: resonance-audio

I'm developing an app using Unity (2017.2.03f) and Google Resonance (v1.1.1) for mobile phones. When testing the application on the Samsung S7, there is a loud constant beep heard in the scenes where there are 1st order ambisonc audio playing. This issue did not occur when testing the app on the two other devices that I have at hand - Pixel XL or the Nexus 5x.

Also, in some scenes, I've used a lowpass filter on the ResonanceAudioMixer ehich seem to be able to reduce the level of the beep.

1. Have anyone had any similar issues with the Samsung S7, or any other phones?
2. Does anyone have any idea about what could be causing the issue?

Any input would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Could you share a bug report on our github page with the sound sample you are using? https://github.com/resonance-audio/resonance-audio-unity-sdk
I am not sure if this is a bug in the Resonance Audio SDK since it doesn't perform any platform specific calculations but we'd be happy to look at it once you help us reproducing the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Julius! I've submitted a new issue at the Github page.

Comment: I finally found the cause of this issue, and it was after all not related to the Resonace plugin, sorry for the false alarm!

It turned out that the recordings, done with the Sennheiser Ambeo contained unwanted high frequency content (not sure how it got there) at around 19.7 kHz, which in turn made three generations of Samsung phones and an iPhone to produce a beep at about 4.3 kHz. When the high frequency content was removed, the beep also dissapeared.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue with the audio recording and not with Resonance Audio plugin. Please see original poster's comment above for details.